# Why is it that the Zoom app on tv box don't have a video icon?

Tags: video-conference, zoom-cloud-meetings

I already installed USB camera app to my tv box and the camera is working. But when I try to call on messenger the camera icon in messenger is not working the recepient cannot see me but I can see him.
I try calling on zoom but there is no camera icon in the app. I can see the other participants but they cannot see me.